# Can we or should we parallel H-bridge module for increse current?

Tags: l298, motordriver, tb6612fng

Can we parallel H-bridge input and output for increse current?

For specific I select 2 case

1. L298N (BJT based)
2. TB6612FNG (Mosfet based)

For L298N as shown in datasheet suggested to parallel chanel to increse current.
For TB6612FNG It have designed dead time.
If we can or we already did it.
The question are

1. How to ensure it will not short-circuit between chanel?
2. What about load sharing? if to chanel not share load equally, that means maximun current not twice value of 1 chanel.

Comment: In theory with FETs it works due to the positive temperature coefficients. In the same theory it did not work with Darlingtons though people did it anyway, but it has been at least 20 years since using a Darlington bridge like the L298 was justified.

Comment: [This](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN4833.pdf) may help stir thoughts.

Comment: Don't forget the behaviour during switching either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If this is about parallel controlled IC's it may not work unless there is a way to synchronize them*. If the datasheets do not specify being able to sync with other IC's then you cannot do so.

Individual MOSFETs with same part number, and hopefully same batch number will track each other very well. If there is a source resistor used to sense current all parallel MOSFETs need to use the same current sensor. Internally a MOSFET is an array of parallel transistors used to build up the current rating, so parallel MOSFETs share loading very well.

As for preventing "shoot-through" the PWM controller and design topology help insure there is dead-time so that 1 MOSFET is switched OFF before the other MOSFET is turned ON.

Comment: This is just H-bridge. no current control. I guess if we just paralel in put of IC maybe it will sync??  Do you have any idea how to set up the experiment to see if it work?

Comment: @Mlab You would have to build it at your own risk, and response time of non-synchronous ICs is NOT going to be the same. Nanoseconds of difference in the outputs could result in destructive shoot-through. I recommend **NOT** doing this.

Answer (score 5):

It is bad practice to blindly parallel drivers without knowing how to estimate the power dissipation and heat rise.

Generally you choose drivers and heatsinks so that they are capable of driving the DCR coil resistance for surge starts with much less voltage drop than the DCR.  Your MOSFET H bridge specs are:

- Output current: IOUT = 1.2 A(ave)/3.2 A (peak)
- Output low ON resistor: 0.5Ω (upper+lower Typ. @ VM ≥ 5 V)

Therefore the motor DCR must be matched to the driver. 3.2A peak implies a ratio of I=Vbat/(2Ron+DCR). Since there are two FETs active , it is 2Ron.

If you need more current, consider a better bridge driver instead.  6644 family and up instead of 6612

Comment: I understand that  changing module is direct path to go but It will very handy if I can parallel module or atleast can you tell me what will happen or might be happen if I did it??

Comment: Unless you can control deadband carefully, any skew in timing can cause Shoot-thru or a short across supply thru both drivers.  Layout is critical so that positive feedback does not amplify ringing ,so layout must be tight and carefully planned for crosstalk.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple devices in parallel simply give you more of the same problem you already have with an H-bridge - namely that you need to allow enough dead time for one side to turn off fully before you turn on the other side.  With a single device, it can manage its own dead time to some extent.  With multiple devices, your controlling micro will need to handle it.  Use the datasheets to find the worst-case dead time required for your device, then double it to allow for tolerances between devices, and use that time in your micro.

Then we get onto device types.  BJTs are vulnerable to thermal runaway, so in general they should *not* be used in parallel unless the device has some kind of additional circuitry to prevent this.  MOSFETs do not generally suffer from this, so they are safer to use in parallel.  However MOSFETs do still have the disadvantage that since their on-resistance will not be exactly the same, one device will still have more current through it than the other.  You'll need to use the max/min on-resistance specs to work out how bad the balance between devices could be.